# Count right word from a specific variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How should I be able to count the word "asdf" in the variable aaa with value "asdf_dd_adf34asdf_sdf"?

```
DECLARE @aaa varchar;

SET @aaa = 'asdf_dd_adf34asdf_sdf';
```

Answer (score 3):

Count how many characters goes away if you remove the occurances of the word, and divide by the length of the word:

```
(len(aaa) - len(replace(aaa, 'asdf', ''))) / len('asdf')
```

Comment: Yes, this is a common method to do so. Pity that it doesn't work well with values ending with a space, but it should work for the OP, as they want *words* (so no trailing spaces).